# Unexpected infinite while loop traversing when I am doing an operation with while loop

Tags: c++

look the below program. When compiled it, the loop is not terminating. That is not an expected behaviour. Anyone please explain this reason?

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
{
    int nIntValue = 0;
    int nTempVal = 100;
    for( int nLoop = 1; nLoop <= 25; nLoop++ )
    {
        nTempVal = nTempVal / nLoop;
    }
    // Print the value of nIntVal
    while( nIntVal == 0 )
    {
        nIntVal += nTempVal;
        cout<<nIntVal;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debugging tip: print the value of `nTempVal` each time you're dividing it.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, what  is `nIntVal`?
Second, assuming its really `nIntValue`, when you enter the following loop:

```
while( nIntVal == 0 )
    {
        nIntVal += nTempVal;
        cout<<nIntVal;
    }
```

it is 0.

As for nTempVal, you are dividing 100 by `(1*2*3*...*25)`. You are using `int` type which means all values are rounded. But even if you didn't, the exact result of the first loop would be `0.000000000000000000000006447` which is pretty close to zero.

So both `nIntVal` and `nTempVal` are 0, and you are stuck here (0+0 = 0 and the loop never ends).

Comment: assume nIntVal is an integer value and it is used to some purpose in the code. How can you say nTempVal is zero? it is not zero. initially it's value is 100. after completion o for loop nTempVal is not 0. then how you say it's value is 0?

Comment: @sajeesh, then please provide the _full_ code right away, without having us to guess that a variable was declared somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

`nTempVal = 0`. So the loop is not terminated.

You can easily find such error with `debugger`

Comment: ok iagree nTempVal is 0. but i have doubt , if an integer value is devided with any nuber for 25 times, it value become 0?

Comment: nTempVal is initialised to 100 and then divided by (1 * 2 * 3.. *25). The result of this will be less than one which is truncated to zero when converted to an integer.

Comment: @sajeesh - you are performing integer division. Please look it up